# C# Multithreading accessing single method

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to process 60000 files in a single shot using a method. How can use threading to increase the performance and lower the processing time. If I use multiple threads which access the same method, will it throw error? Can you give me a sample how to process it.

Comment: please give more information about the files. What do you do with them and where are they? If your IO operations use one hardware drive, then it doesn't support simultaneous multiple IOs

Comment: These files are located in the server where the application will be running.

Comment: take a look at [this book](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). It will get you started with threading.

Answer (score 2):

Where are the 60000 files?  All in one folder on a local hard disk/SSD or spread out on mutiple disks/LAN servers?  If the're all local, there may be not much to gain by parallel processing, (there will be some, but is the gain worth the complication?).  If the files span disks/servers, then there is potentially a huge performance boost available.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: All the files are in the same server where the application will be running.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Microsoft tutorial with explanations and samples on coding a multithreaded project.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx